# BASH CURL SCRIPT / Automatic Web Form Login

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

I need to login automatically to a Wi-fi network with a shell script (terminal / OS X).

The web form submit is controlled through a Javascript:

```
function submitAction(){
      var link = document.location.href;
      var searchString = "redirect=";
      var equalIndex = link.indexOf(searchString);
      var redirectUrl = "";
      var urlStr = "";
      if(equalIndex > 0) {
            equalIndex += searchString.length;
            redirectUrl = link.substring(equalIndex);
            if(redirectUrl.length > 0){
        if(redirectUrl.length > 255)
            redirectUrl = redirectUrl.substring(0,255);         document.forms[0].redirect_url.value = redirectUrl;
        }
      } 
      document.forms[0].buttonClicked.value = 4;
      document.forms[0].submit(); }
```

Two fields are used (password & username) and the form is method="post".

Question:
Is it possible to do this through a shell script in OS X? How do I proceed when the submit is triggered this way with Javascript?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about OS X but I think it can be helpful for you anyway.
This is what I did:

1. Take FF + Firebug
2. Go to Network tab in the Firebug and set persistent data.
3. Do whatever you need to authenticate yourself via wifi router's
   webpage.
4. Find request the browser sent with the credentials.
5. Click it with right mouse button and choose Copy as cURL
6. Past it to the script file.
7. If it's self signed SSL cert than append -k for CURL
8. Enjoy